# Error While Uploading Image Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a trouble while uploading image. The error says: include(CUploadFile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

I have a table in my db, `tbl_barang` (`id_barang`, `nama_barang`, `id_merk`, `harga`, `foto`, `deskripsi`)

This is my model, Barang.php

```
<?php

    class Barang extends CActiveRecord {

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName() {
        return 'tbl_barang';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('nama_barang, id_merk, harga, foto, deskripsi', 'required'),
            array('harga', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('nama_barang', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('id_merk', 'length', 'max'=>3),
            array('foto', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true,), //menentukan file, tipe file, dan boleh empty pada validasi upload foto
            array('id_barang, nama_barang, id_merk, harga, foto, deskripsi', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations() {
        return array();
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id_barang' => 'Id Barang',
            'nama_barang' => 'Nama Barang',
            'id_merk' => 'Id Merk',
            'harga' => 'Harga',
            'foto' => 'Foto',
            'deskripsi' => 'Deskripsi',
        );
    }

    public function search() {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id_barang',$this->id_barang);
        $criteria->compare('nama_barang',$this->nama_barang,true);
        $criteria->compare('id_merk',$this->id_merk,true);
        $criteria->compare('harga',$this->harga);
        $criteria->compare('foto',$this->foto,true);
        $criteria->compare('deskripsi',$this->deskripsi,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Then my controller, BarangController.php

```
class BarangController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */

    //menentukan layout
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    //menentukan folder tempat penyimpanan
    const URLUPLOAD='/../images/barang';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters() {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id) {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate() {
        $model=new Barang; //panggil model Barang

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Barang'])) { //jika data dikirim
            //cek file
            $cekfile = $model->image=CUploadFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');

            if(empty($cekfile)) { //jika file kosong
                //ambil data yang diinput
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Barang'];
                $model->save();
            } else { //jika file tidak kosong
                //ambil data yang diinput
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Barang'];
                //ambil file
                $model->image = CUploadFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');
                if($model->save()) { //jika data disimpan
                    //upload image ke folder
                    $model->image->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.self::URLUPLOAD.$model->image.'');

                    //alihkan ke halaman index/function actionIndex()
                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_barang));
                }
            }
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Barang'])) {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Barang'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_barang));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id) {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex() {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Barang');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin() {
        $model=new Barang('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Barang']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Barang'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
     */
    public function loadModel($id) {
        $model=Barang::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model) {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='barang-form') {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

In `_form.php` I just changed the textfiled into filefield in the foto's row. I really confused why it cannot uploaded. I hope anyone can help me and teach me how to fix it. Thank you

Comment: :-) what the other commentators seem to be missing is that there is no  class CUploadFile, which is probably why you're getting the error. The class you need is CUploadedFile. See my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you should have this type of code regarding to image foto file.

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'foto'); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'foto'); ?>
<php echo $form->error($model,'foto'); ?>
</div>
```

Now you need to edit your controller file.

Now in your controller file. You need to changes the below method.

It is your controller, i try to remove errors from this controller. you first try this.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Barang; 

    if(isset($_POST['Barang'])) //jika data dikirim
    {

        $cekfile = $model->foto=CUploadFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');

        if(empty($cekfile)){ //jika file kosong

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Barang'];
            $model->save();
        }
        else{ //jika file tidak kosong

        $model->attributes=$_POST['Barang'];

        $model->foto= CUploadFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');
        if($model->save()){ //jika data disimpan

        $model->foto->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.self::URLUPLOAD.$model->foto.'');


        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_barang));
        }
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

if above method giving error too. then you try below method.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
 $model=new Barang;

 if(isset($_POST['Barang']))
 {

   $model->attributes  =  $_POST['Barang'];
   $model->foto        =  CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'foto');

   if(empty($model->foto)){ 
      $model->save();
   }
   else
   {                  
   if($model->save())
      // i have made a folder on root->media and create folder, its name is images.
      // so you create your folder first to for uploading your images.
      $fullImgSource = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/media/images/'.$model->foto;
      $model->foto->saveAs($fullImgSource);
      $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_barang));
   }
   }
   $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

I hope, it will help you.

thanks.

Comment: thanks, Mr. Rizwan. Now, my problem is the foto is always blank when I try to add / create it. Why? Can you teach me how to fix it??

Comment: When we upload any file image, then we should give in form tage i.e. enctype="multipart/form-data", i think you do not giving this. If any thing is write, then you follow the link, it should help you. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

Comment: Thank you for teach me I have tried it and success. Thanks a lot for teach me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
Instead of
`$model->image = CUploadFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');`
try
`$model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'foto');`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

> $cekfile = CUploadFile::getInstance($model, 'foto'); // for getting
>   image instance.
>
> $model->foto = $cekfile->name; // assigning foto name to model
>   attribute.
>
> $cekfile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.self::URLUPLOAD.$model->image.'');
>   //for uploading image in folder

Also check whether the image upload path is correct.

Thanks