# how rename image before upload in Yii framework

Tags: yii

I have follow yii site to work with upload image, code here:

```
class ItemController extends CController
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Item;
        if(isset($_POST['Item']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Item'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
            {
                $model->image->saveAs('path/to/localFile');
                // redirect to success page
            }
        }
        $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```

however how can I rename file by currentdate+filename.png and upload to path,also I need code for update and delete.
thankyou very much

I have resolve this problem:

```
public function currentDate(){
        $date = date('m-d-Y-h-i-s', time());
        return $date;
    }

public function actionCreate(){
        $model = new News();

        if(isset($_POST['News']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['News'];          
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images');
            $fileName = "{$this->currentDate()}-{$uploadedFile}";
            $model->images = $fileName;         
            if($model->save()){ 
              $uploadedFile->saveAs("upload/".$fileName);
              $this->redirect(array('news/index'));
            }else{
                $model = new News();
                $this->render('create',
                            array('model' =>$model,
                            'result'=>'insert new fail !',
                )); 
            }
        }else{
            $this->render('create',
            array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359685/error-while-uploading-image-yii  In question itself you have answer.

Comment: my question is that how to rename file when we upload,for example the file is naming test.png, when I upload to folder, I want have file in folder is naming currentdate-test.png,thankyou your answer

Comment: now I have own solution for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model=new News;

if(isset($_POST['News']))
{

$model->attributes=$_POST['News'];  

$name       = $_FILES['News']['name']['images'];
$filename   = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext        = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$newName        = date("m-d-Y-h-i-s", time())."-".$filename.'.'.$ext;

$model->images  = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'images');

if($model->save())

  $fullImgSource = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/'.$newName;
  $model->images->saveAs($fullImgSource);
  $model->images = $newName;
  $model->save();
  $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
  $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

Comment: what is advance in your ways ?

Answer (score 1):

To rename the file after upload and update in DB, try this code.

```
    $model=new Item;
    if(isset($_POST['Item']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Item'];

        if($model->save())
        {
            $imageName = @$_FILES["MenuItems"]["name"]["image"];
            $uniqueName = (imageName . $model->id) . '.' . (end(explode('.', $imageName)));
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $model->image->saveAs('path/to/localFile/'.$uniqueName);
            $model->image = $uniqueName;
            $model->save();
            // redirect to success page
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method that I had created later to upload file and change its name before upload it :

```
public static function createAttach($model, $imageAttrName) {
    $model->$imageAttrName = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, $imageAttrName);
    $fecha = date('YmdHms');

    if ($model->$imageAttrName) {
        $attach_src = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../upload/' . $fecha.'.'.$model->$imageAttrName->getExtensionName(); //. '_' . $model->$imageAttrName;
        $model->$imageAttrName->saveAs($attach_src);
        $model->$imageAttrName = $fecha.'.'.$model->$imageAttrName->getExtensionName();// . '_' . $model->$imageAttrName;
    }
}
```